# how to disable the e-mail verification on wp-admin/options-general.php multisite admin e-mail

Tags: admin, email

[image]

I have a multsite that has a bunch of blank e-mail addresses in the admin e-mail address feilds, and I just want to update them without the e-mails being verified.

Background is that I am a web developer working on a site for a frachise that has 200+ stores, and the manager/owner of the franchise should be getting e-mails from the site that depends on this feild but we don't want to bother with checking in to make sure they clicked the link. I just want to update them all and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found if you go to http://sitename.com/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id={{id}} and set it here, it doesnt require verification.